# Codename One close PopUp dialog only when I tap the screen

Tags: dialog, popup, codenameone

I have an Android with many explicative popup dialogs.

Those I want to close only if a close button inside is pressed, not when I tap on the screen outside the dialog.

I am using `setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds` set to false, but this only seems to work for dialogs that are not the popup style.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour also for the popup dialogs?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public void dialogTest () {
    
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Test");
    dialog.add(new Button ("Test")).add(new Button("TestTwo"));
    dialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false);  // flag is set to false, but dialog closes anyway when I tap on the screen
    dialog.showPopupDialog(buttonTest);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rainer Yes, it's possible. First, however, a brief explanation. For reasons I don't know, in the Dialog.java file on line 1176, `disposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds = true;` was imposed. You can check it yourself: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/1ad583bae9e05954c6bff852649d3b6d8264414b/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Dialog.java#L1176

That's why `dialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false);` doesn't work for you, because it was designed to work only with normal Dialogs and not with Dialogs popups.

This behavior is also specified in Javadoc, so it seems an intentional choice, although I don't know why and, in particular, I don't know if there are differences between Android and iOS on this point, since they have different default ways to create popup dialogs (and maybe the problem is right here).

Said that, the solution is very simple: it works in the Simulator, I'll let you try if it works on real devices too. Simply override the `onShow` method in this way:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(new BorderLayout()){
    @Override
    protected void onShow() {
         this.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false);
    }
};
[...]
d.showPopupDialog(buttonTest);
```

Comment: many thanks for posting this elegant and simple solution. Shai responded a little earlier, so I have already changed the dialogs into Interaction, but I will definitely try this approach for the next situation. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: Trying it out today ... even though it works perfectly in the simulator, on the installed app the background behind the dialog  turns completely black until the dialog is closed. Have you made similar experiences?

Comment: No, I tried that code in the Simulator only. Does it happen on both Android and iPhone?

Comment: I have seen your response only today. The issue with the background was not related to your code sample. The problem was with the CSS configuration. I had a line dialog.setUIID("Popup") that was causing an interference. Overriding the dialog actually solved my problem. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you show a `Dialog` (popup or otherwise) the form behind it isn't "real". Since a `Dialog` IS A `Form` it takes over the entire screen always. What you see in the background is a screenshot of the previous `Form`.

What you're interested in is `InteractionDialog` which also has a popup option. It works in a different way and allows you to interact with the `Form` below it. See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/picking-dialog-type.html

Comment: I tried to add a different answer that does not require the use of InteractionDialog.